# Geometric distribution: Collecting cute cats contained conscientiously.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have just exposed myself to the geometric distribution, and have five fabricated questions based on the following information: You are collecting cats from baskets. A basket contains a cat with probability $0.1$.

> 1) What is the probability that the first $25$ baskets that you check have no cats?

My logic: Probability that the first basket is empty is $0.9$, 2nd ${0.9}^2$, 25th ${0.9}^{25} \approx 0.718$

> 2) What is the probability that the $25^{th}$ basket is the first to contain a cat?

My logic: This is the geometric distribution which has equation $(1-p)^{n} \cdot p$, where we have $n = 25, p = 0.1$: $(1-0.1)^{25} \cdot 0.1 \approx 7.18E{-3}$

> 3) What is the expected number of baskets opened until a cat is found?

My logic: Geometric distribution equation works again: $E(X) = \frac{1-p}{p} = \frac{1-.1}{.1} = 9$. Which is the number of trials expected before a success, so 9-1 ratio.

> 4) What is the variance of the number of baskets opened until a cat is found?

My logic: Once again a geometric distribution equations should hold: $\frac{1-p}{p^2} = \frac{1-0.1}{0.1^2} = 90$

> 5) Now suppose that you need to find three cats(to fulfil your happiness), what is the expected value and variance of the number of baskets that will need to be checked? Assuming the cats are distinct and that each basket has the same probability of 0.1 of containing any one of the three needed cats.

My logic: The expected value is just three times greater, so 9? I have no idea what to do no the variance side of things though.

Does everything seem correct? How do I go about question 5? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your expected value seems off - the expected number of baskets opened should be 10 - the expected number of empty baskets is 9. Please confirm you are interpreting the question correctly.

Comment: @user130512 I see now that the geometric distribution is based on number of trials BEFORE first success, which means the 10th trial would be the expected value for first success. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the number of cats you need to find is greater than 1, the probability distribution for the number of baskets you must check becomes what is called *negative binomial*.  The negative binomial distribution has a number of different forms, but the one that is applicable in your case is the following.  Suppose we are interested in the random number $X$ of the *total* number of baskets checked until we observe the $r^{\rm th}$ cat (in your case, $r = 3$).  Thus $X$ includes those baskets with cats.  Then the probability that $X = k$ is given by $$\Pr[X = k] = \binom{k-1}{k-r}p^r (1-p)^{k-r}, \quad k = r, r+1, r+2, \ldots,$$ where $p$ is the individual probability of observing a cat (here, $p = 0.1$).  To understand why this is the case, consider the situation where $X = k$ for some fixed $k \ge r$.  Then among these $k$ baskets checked, the final basket must always contain a cat (otherwise, we would not have stopped checking).  Among the remaining $k-1$ baskets, there are $\binom{k-1}{r-1}$ distinct ways that we could have observed the ordering of the remaining $r-1$ cats.  Each of the $r$ baskets containing cats has a probability of $p$ of being observed, and the $k-r$ baskets had a probability of $1-p$ of being observed.

The expected value and variance of such a distribution are given by $${\rm E}[X] = \frac{r}{p}, \quad {\rm Var}[X] = \frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}.$$  One method of proof involves some algebra, with the assumption (which is intuitively true but does require formal proof) that $$\sum_{k=r}^\infty \Pr[X = k] = \sum_{k=r}^\infty \binom{k-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^{k-r} = 1.$$  We have $$\begin{align*} {\rm E}[X] &= \sum_{k=r}^\infty k \Pr[X = k] \\ &= \sum_{k=r}^\infty k \frac{(k-1)!}{(k-r)!(r-1)!} p^r (1-p)^{k-r} \\ &= \sum_{k=r}^\infty \frac{r}{p} \cdot \frac{k!}{(k-r)! r!} p^{r+1} (1-p)^{k-r} \\ &= \frac{r}{p} \sum_{k=r}^\infty \binom{k+1-1}{k+1-(r+1)} p^{r+1} (1-p)^{(k+1)-(r+1)} \\ &= \frac{r}{p} \sum_{k=r+1}^\infty \binom{k-1}{k-(r+1)} p^{r+1} (1-p)^{k-(r+1)} \\ &= \frac{r}{p}, \end{align*}$$  where the last equality is true because the resulting sum is the sum over a negative binomial distribution with $r+1$ instead of $r$ (which is still $1$).  Similarly, we can show using the same method that $${\rm E}[X(X+1)] = \sum_{k=r}^\infty k(k+1) \Pr[X = k] = \frac{r(r+1)}{p^2},$$ and the variance is obtained from $${\rm Var}[X] = {\rm E}[X^2] - {\rm E}[X]^2 = {\rm E}[X(X+1)] - {\rm E}[X] - {\rm E}[X]^2.$$  Of course, this is more algebraically involved than the other answer, but I just wanted to provide some additional background and mention the properties of this distribution, which we can see is a useful generalization of the geometric distribution.

Comment: This makes sense. I thought it may have taken a new distribution, and I used logic to work out(aswell as the first comment I received) that the E(X) should be 9, but only because X is the number of fails prior to the first success. Then adding 1 and multiplying by three gave me the E(Y), where Y is for three cats, which yields the same answer as the above equation you listed results, which makes sense. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an infinite number of baskets, all with the same probabilities, with the probability of one basket containing a cat being independent of the other baskets (as suggested in your question).

Then, denoting the random variable of interest in (5) by $Y$, (i.e. the number of baskets to be checked before finding 3 cats) we can write

$Y = X_1 + X_2 +X_3$, where the $X_i$ are independent copies of the RV considered in the previous parts (i.e. how many baskets must be checked before finding one cat).

Linearity of expectation gives $E(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^3E(X_i)$, and because the $X_i$ are independent we have

$var(Y)  =  \sum_{i=1}^3 var(X_i)$.

Comment: That all makes sense, thank you for that. One further query: A comment is suggesting 3) is wrong, I simply used the formula, so I would assume it is right, but I can see what they are saying, perhaps it is 9 baskets were opened without a cat, and then a cat was found? Is that how I interpret E(X) here?

Comment: Well, whenever geometric random variables are used, there is always a bit of ambiguity as there are two definitions: one would be, the number of baskets opened *before* the first cat is found; another would be, the number of baskets opened *including the one which contains the first cat*. You just need to be $100\%$ sure you are using the formula appropriate to your definition of a geometric RV. But your method is totally fine.