# When to use Binomial or Neg Binomial?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

I have a problem that I'm not sure which distribution to use:

12 Toll employees were let go for taking more than 25,000 dollars in tolls. Lets say that one of the people let go on one day collected from 470 automobiles. Then lets say that this employee took 10 of those 470 tolls about 2.13% of all tolls for that day.

If the auditors randomly samples(without replacement) 50 of those 470 tolls for investigation, what's the probability they will find at least one stolen bill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written extensively on this topic.  Here are some links to help you tell the difference:

[Apple's Binomially Distributed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831389/apples-binomially-distributed/831402#831402)

[Binomial distribution question regarding one after another selection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921733/binomial-distribution-question-regarding-one-after-another-selection/921780#921780)

[Which model to use ? (probability problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833558/which-model-to-use-probability-problem/833630#833630)

[Geometric distribution: Collecting cute cats contained conscientiously.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736526/geometric-distribution-collecting-cute-cats-contained-conscientiously/737704#737704)

That said, your question is neither binomial nor negative binomial, because the sampling occurs without replacement.  Your question pertains to a **hypergeometric** distribution, which is one of the first distributions to consider whenever you are confronted with any sampling that is done without replacement.  Example question for such a distribution:

[Hypergeometric Distribution Confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/824116/hypergeometric-distribution-confusion/824130#824130)

Comment: thanks for your information, heropup!